# Test to evaluate attention in Autism

Tags: intelligence, autism

I am looking for the most reliable and widely used tests for attention measurement in autistic persons. Can anybody help me to find such tests? I have read about some IQ tests including DAS, WASI and their sub-tests, however I didn't find any related sub-test to attention.

Comment: What do you mean by "attention"? What are you hoping to evaluate in regards to attention in autism? What they pay attention to? How long they pay attention to things? How easily they can switch between attending to various things when an external reward is provided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*You don't say what language you want the tests to be in, so I'm assuming English.*

In the book *Evidence-Based Assessment in ASD (Autism Spectrum Disorder)*, author Kenneth J. Aitken "describes and analyses a wide range of available Autism Spectrum Disorder (ASD) assessment measures". The chapter on "Attention" lists the following tests:

- Conners' Continuous Auditory Test of Attention (CATA)
- Conners' Continuous Performance Test II - Third Revision (CCPT 3)
- d2 Test of Attention (d2)
- Sustained Attention to Response Test (SART)
- Test of Everyday Attention (TEA)
- Test of Everyday Attention for Children (TEA-Ch)
- Test for Variables of Attention - 8th Edition 2015 (TOVA-8.2)

The book also explains what kind of attention each test assesses, why the test is useful in relation to Autism, and research findings.

You may want to check your local university or public library to look into a copy of that book.

---

There are many widely used, valid, and reliable tests of attention that an experienced clinician or researcher can use to assess attention in a patient with Autism. Just open any recent handbook or textbook on either attention or Autism and see what measures they use and describe.